# Resistor Squeaks When Cooling Down

Tags: resistors

I have a series of 1 ohm/ 4 Watts that each theoretically takes up 2W. It got pretty hot while in the circuit, and when I plugged off the power they kinda gave out some "tearing sound".

Does anyone know why that happens?

Comment: What kind of circuit are you using? are you sure it was the resistor? what type of resistor are you using? carbon film, metal film, wirewound, etc...? How much voltage are you applying? just because a resistor can dissipate 2W it doesn't meant that you should run it to its maximum.

Comment: Squeaking/tearing/metal-on-metal sound with heat could indicate mismatched temperature-coefficient-of-expansion causing mechanical strain... please use the `edit` link to provide more information. Adding a photo could help uncover key details.

Comment: Is it the resistors or the PCB and soldered connections squeaking?

Answer (score 0):

A 4_watt resistor likely needs force_air cooling, or mounting on a metal panel to remove the heat.

Depending on the leads, soldered onto PCB boards, is not the path to reliable systems.

How do we know this?

The thermal resistance of PCB traces, of standard 1.4 mil thickness from the standard 1 ounce of copper foil per square foot, is 70 degree Centigrade per watt per SQUARE OF FOIL.

Thus a path of size 0.020" by 1" (having 50 squares of foil) on each lead of a 2_watt resistor, with 50 * 70 = 3,500 degree Centigrade (temperature gradient) per lead, given the 2 leads producing 1,750 degree Centrigrade temperature rise,

has the RESISTOR self_cooling only by **RADIATING**

You can do better than that.